# TestNG - generating errors by unexpected exceptions

Tags: java, testing, testng

I would like to know, is there any way to set up TestNG to handle unexpected exceptions like errors and not like failures?

I tried to throw RuntimeException in my test and it was considered as failure, not like an error.
TestNG documentation talks only about success and failure states - 
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#success-failure.

I would like to have TestNG behaviour similar to JUnit in first question on address
http://www.querycat.com/question/d1c9a200f18e6829cb06dda8eda8ad61

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Ignore what I had before. Unfortunately, I'm fairly certain the answer to your question is no, TestNG does not have this feature. The entirety of the TestNG documentation is [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html), so if a feature isn't listed on that page it probably doesn't exist. Remember that although TestNG is inspired by JUnit, it should not be considered a super-set of JUnit's features. The only thing I can think of if you want your test suite to catastrophically fail on an exception is to make it call `System.exit(1)`.

Comment: I will live with this. Perhaps I will have a look at the TestNG source code if there is something to simulate JUnit behaviour.

Comment: @Aries If you just want this for reporting you could parse the junit XML that testng produces and change errors to failures if the error type was anything other than an AssertionError.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the wrong exception. 
JUnit is distinguishing between success, failure (AssertionException thrown by assertXXX) and error (all other not expected exception).

If you know that a method will throw an exception you can catch it with @Test(expected=MyExpectedException).

Comment: Perhaps I do not made myself clear. I know how to catch expected exceptions.
I want unexpected exceptions to cause test error. But they are causing test failure.